# How do I clean a kitchen sink spray hose?

Tags: plumbing, cleaning, kitchens, sink

My kitchen sink has one of those sprayer-on-a-hose things off to the side of the main faucet. It has a clear plastic hose that pulls out to spray stuff around the sink. That hose has green stuff growing in it. It was like that when I bought this house so I don't know what conditions led to the situation. I can tell you that the hose is very rarely used now because the water coming through it stinks.

Can I clean that hose? I'm thinking maybe I could remove it and soak it in something. Maybe bleach or vinegar? Or should I just replace it? Is that an easy fix or would I need to replace the entire faucet to get the hose? Also, if anyone has any idea how this growth might have started, I'd like to know to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: I agree with SchwartzE to replace it -- but as for how it started, it likely happened if it wasn't used much, as most stuff won't grow under water.  (of course, the stuff that will is anaerobic, which tends to be fairly nasty stuff)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just replace the hose.  You would probably have to take it apart to clean it anyway.  I found [replacement hoses](http://www.acehardwareoutlet.com/productdetails.aspx?sku=40086&source=GoogleBase) for around $4.  The [directions](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/245571/easy_steps_to_replace_a_kitchen_spray.html?cat=6) seem fairly straightforward.

Comment: I agree. not worth cleaning. buy a new one....